# Is there any counter example for this $ f $?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

First sorry about the grammar and words errors in my post since English is not my native tongue.

Here $ f $ is a countinuous function on $ x=0 $, and the limit

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(\tan x) - f(x)}{x^3}
$$

exists. My question is: is $f$ differentiable on $x = 0$?

My opinion is NO since it restricts the derivative's definition. So I want to find a counter-example for this claim.

I searched around the math.se, and found this: [$f$ differentiable at $0\iff\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285914/f-differentiable-at-0-iff-lim-x-to-0-fracf2x-fxx-exists). I draw my wrong proposition back and sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: The Riemann example is not a continuous function on all of $\Bbb R$ (it's not continuous at rational numbers). Is the continuity assumption important to you?

Comment: In the cases $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$ the derivative at $0$ is three times this limit!  I wonder if we can show that the derivative necessarily exists and equals  three times the limit

Comment: @geetha290krm When $f$ is the identity, the limit is $1/3$ of the derivative at $0$.

Comment: @FShrike I wanted to say $1/3-$ times the limit in both cases.

Comment: @GregMartin no not at $\mathbb{R}$, I miswrote the condition, just continuous on $x=0$ is fine.

Comment: well, since $\tan x=x+x^3/3+o(x^3)$, the 3 times' conclusion seems sensible.

Comment: after some tinkering, I believe the following alternative is true: Fix any $\epsilon>0$, and fix any real function $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$, if the limit 
$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f({(1+\epsilon)}\tan(x))-f(x)}{x^{3}}$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$. If $\epsilon = 0$, then it gets tricky as the repeated iterations of $\arctan(x)$ do not go to zero fast enough for small $x$ (if at all).